# tuning resultset without temp table

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Table1 (orgumcae)

```
caseid | auth_status_summary | delegate_system
-------+---------------------+----------------
100    | 1                   | 14
200    | 2                   | 13
```

SQL:

```
create table orgumcae(caseid int, auth_status_summary int, delegate_system int);
insert into orgumcae values(100, 1, 14);
insert into orgumcae values(200, 2, 13);
```

Table2 (stringlocale)

```
id  | subid | string
----+-------+--------
148 | 1     | AAA
148 | 2     | BBB
148 | 3     | CCC
148 | 14    | DDD
152 | 11    | WWW
152 | 12    | XXX
152 | 13    | YYY
152 | 14    | ZZZ
```

SQL:

```
create table stringlocale(id int, subid int, string varchar(40));
insert into stringlocale values(148,1,'AAA');
insert into stringlocale values(148,2,'BBB');
insert into stringlocale values(148,14,'DDD');
insert into stringlocale values(152,11,'WWW');
insert into stringlocale values(152,13,'YYY');
insert into stringlocale values(152,14,'ZZZ');
```

Resultset

```
caseid | auth_status_summary |auth_status_summary_string | delegate_system | delegate_system_string
-------+---------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------
100    | 1                   | AAA                       | 14              | ZZZ
200    | 2                   | BBB                       | 13              | YYY
```

There are 2 tables `Table1` and `Table2` and a Resultset. Can I get some help to achieve the Resultset without using temp tables?

Here `auth_status_summary` column of `Table1` denotes 148 value for column `id` of `Table2` and `delegate_system` column of `Table1` denotes 152 value for column `id` of `Table2`, so for `auth_status_summary` use where clause `table2.id = 148` for `delegate_system` use where clause `table2.id = 152`

Comment: It's unclear how the tables are related to each-other (how are the foreign key references defined) and what is the expected logic, which leads to the result you've shown. Also your samples are unreadable - try using "code" blocks in your question.

Comment: There is no foreign key references here. auth_status_summary and delegate_system both refer to subid. auth_status_summary is denoted by value 148 and delegate_system is denoted by value 152

Comment: Values separated by PIPE (|)





caseid | auth_status_summary | delegate_system




100 | 1 | 14

200 | 2 | 13




Table2

id | subid | string

148 | 1 | AAA

148 | 2 | BBB

148 | 3 | CCC

148 | 14 | DDD

152 | 11 | WWW

152 | 12 | XXX

152 | 13 | YYY

152 | 14 | ZZZ





Resultset

caseid | auth_status_summary | auth_status_summary_string | delegate_system | delegate_system_string

100 | 1 | AAA | 14 | ZZZ

200 | 2 | BBB | 13 | YYY

Comment: you can run the below query in ur sql 

create table orgumcae(caseid int, auth_status_summary int, delegate_system int)
insert into orgumcae values(100,1,14)
insert into orgumcae values(200,2,13)

create table stringlocale(id int, subid int, string varchar(40))
insert into stringlocale values(148,1,'AAA')
insert into stringlocale values(148,2,'BBB')
insert into stringlocale values(148,14,'DDD')
insert into stringlocale values(152,11,'WWW')
insert into stringlocale values(152,13,'YYY')
insert into stringlocale values(152,14,'ZZZ')

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. Please edit your original question and make sure, you properly use the Markdown syntax, to make your data readable and/or provide SQL instructions on recreating what you have (i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements) also using proper Markdown. Comments are for determining what is unclear and how, and clarifications should be provided by editing the question (or answer), unless from comments, it'll turn out that the question was clear in the first place.

Comment: added as image for reference

Comment: for auth_status_summary use where clause table2.id = 148

for delegate_system         use where clause table2.id = 152

Comment: I've suggested an edit to the question - it's awaiting peer review. Take a look at it, on what I meant: your additional information should be clearly included into the question, in a readable form, utilizing the Markdown syntax, that StackOverflow uses.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select case_id, t1.auth_status_summary, t2.string, t1.delegate_system, t22.string 
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.auth_status_summary = t2.subid 
inner join table2 as t22 on t1.delegate_system = t22.subid
```

Comment: While this answer might resolve the OP's question, it is suggested that you explain how it works and why it resolves the issue. This helps new developers understand what is going on and how to fix this and similar issues themselves. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: this is not working out when subid is same with 2 different ids
drop table orgumcae
create table orgumcae(caseid int, auth_status_summary int, delegate_system int)
insert into orgumcae values(100,3,14)
insert into orgumcae values(200,2,13)

drop table stringlocale
create table stringlocale(id int, subid int, string varchar(40))
insert into stringlocale values(148,2,'BBB')
insert into stringlocale values(148,3,'CCC')
insert into stringlocale values(148,14,'DDD')
insert into stringlocale values(152,13,'YYY')
insert into stringlocale values(152,14,'ZZZ')

Comment: Thanks for the initial start up. This should work

Select caseid, t1.auth_status_summary, t2.string as auth_status_summary_string, t1.delegate_system, t22.string as delegate_system_string
from orgumcae as t1
inner join stringlocale as t2 on t1.auth_status_summary = t2.subid and t2.id = 148
inner join stringlocale as t22 on t1.delegate_system = t22.subid and t22.id = 152

Comment: Caleb Kleveter - This is old data model where there is a separate table 'Table2' whose 'id' value denotes columns in another table.. auth_status_summary and delegate_system both refer to subid. auth_status_summary is denoted by value 148 and delegate_system is denoted by value 152

Comment: OP's has needed only 2 rows in output but it is coming 3 rows in your query.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
select t1.caseid,
       t1.auth_status_summary,
       t2_auth.string as auth_status_summary_string,
       t1.delegate_system,
       t2_deleg.string as delegate_system_string
  from orgumcae t1
  left outer join stringlocale t2_auth
    on t2_auth.id = 148
   and t2_auth.subid = t1.auth_status_summary
  left outer join stringlocale t2_deleg
    on t2_deleg.id = 152
   and t2_deleg.subid = t1.delegate_system
 order by 1
```

The key part is to use the `Table2` (`stringlocale`) twice, with different aliases.

See this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1195972229dbda9feaf90f6fd869c76e)